# how to find the equation of a line when you are given a point on that line and its normal vector in $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: vectors

I see the answer for this in $\Bbb R^3$, but it's just confusing, can someone show me how to or point me to a place that shows me how to solve a problem like this (in $\Bbb R^2$). 
I am given a point $(3,5)$ on a line and a normal vector $\langle 2,4\rangle$ and asked to give the equation of the line in normal form, general form and parametric form.

Comment: This kind of problems are typically asked in homework where the point is that _your textbook will have explicitly explained a procedure_ for doing it. If you haven't read the appropriate sections of the textbook, now is an excellent time to do so.

Comment: The equation of your line will be of the form: $2y = 4x + c$. Can you go from here?

Comment: If you _have_ read the relevant sections of your textbook, but find a particular part of them confusing, **ask about that** instead of expecting to have your homework done for you here without you learning anything yourself.

Comment: I have seen the working in the text but it is a question about a plane (in R3), I am trying to transfer the method to R2 but am confused. The figures I gave in the question are not the figures in the actual problem as I wanted a method that I could then work through to learn how to do this. I don't want the answer I want the method.

Comment: so Stuart I have my line equation (from the normal vector I'm guessing) then I will substitute the point coordinates into it (x=3, y=5) to get 10 = 12 + c so c is -2) so my line is y = 2x -1 ( dividing out the 2 coefficient of y)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to easily remember the formula to be used is to understand the geometric intuition behind this formula: the points $A=(3,5)$ and $M=(x,y)$ on the line have the same projection on the normal vector $\vec n=\langle 2,4\rangle$, i.e. using the dot product:
$$A\cdot\vec n=M\cdot\vec n\quad\text{ or }\quad 3\cdot2+5\cdot4=3x+5y. $$

As to the parametric form, you have to find a directing vector for the line: since you're given $\vec n=\langle 2,4\rangle$, you can take $\;\vec u=\langle -4,2\rangle$ to obtain
$$M=A+t\vec u=(3-4t,5+2t).$$

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what 'normal form' and 'general form' are, but I'll try to help nonetheless. Perhaps it's useful to include these (standard) forms in your question.

A normal vector of a line with cartesian equation
$$\color{blue}{a}x+\color{blue}{b}y+c=0 \tag{$*$}$$
is the vector $(\color{blue}{a},\color{blue}{b})$ so if you are given this normal vector, substitute the given point into the equation $(*)$ to find $c$.

Alternatively, use the following form for a line with a given normal vector as above and through the point $(\color{green}{x_0},\color{green}{y_0})$ directly:
$$\color{blue}{a}(x-\color{green}{x_0})+\color{blue}{b}(y-\color{green}{y_0})=0$$
And then perhaps you have already seen a procedure to convert one form (type of equation) into another?

Comment: so from this I get ax + by +c = 0, subbing in normal vector I get 2x + 4y + c = 0 the sub in the coordinated form the point to get 2*3 +4*5 + c =0 which gives me 6 + 20 + c =0 so c is -26 which gives me the formula 2x + 4y - 26 = 0 rearranging I get 4y = -2x + 26 and divide by 4 to get y = -1/2x + 6.5 ( I know should write it 6 and a half but dont know how to write fractions on here yet)

Comment: @guy You get an equation of that form, yes: use blue to get the normal vector right and then find c or, alternatively, use green to immediately get the point on the line correct as well.